# How to convert D3 data array-of-objects from long-format to wide-format in JavaScript and D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have got data is in this format:

```
let data_sales = [
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2001Q2", "Type": "House", "NumSales": 10 },
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2001Q2", "Type": "Unit", "NumSales": 20 },
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2001Q2", "Type": "Land", "NumSales": 30 },
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2002Q1", "Type": "Unit", "NumSales": 40 },
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2002Q1", "Type": "House", "NumSales": 50 },
  { "Suburb": "keilor", "YearQtr": "2006Q4", "Type": "House", "NumSales": 48 },
  { "Suburb": "keilor", "YearQtr": "2007Q4", "Type": "House", "NumSales": 61 },
  { "Suburb": "box", "YearQtr": "2011Q2", "Type": "House", "NumSales": 24 },
  { "Suburb": "box", "YearQtr": "2011Q4", "Type": "Unit", "NumSales": 26 },
  { "Suburb": "box", "YearQtr": "2008Q3", "Type": "Land", "NumSales": 5 }
]
```

And I want it in this format:

```
data_sales__wide = [
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2001Q2", "House": 10, "Unit": 20, "Land": 30 },
  { "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2002Q1", "House": 40, "Unit": 50 },
  { "Suburb": "keilor", "YearQtr": "2006Q4", "House": 48 },
  { "Suburb": "keilor", "YearQtr": "2007Q4", "House": 61 },
  { "Suburb": "box", "YearQtr": "2011Q2", "House": 24, "Unit": 26 },
  { "Suburb": "box", "YearQtr": "2008Q3", "Land": 5 }
]
```

See how multiple rows are pivoted to one row, hence long format to wide format.

So far, I have tried several techniques and closest I've got to my desired result is with the code below (inspired by @MikeBostock's comment on pivoting here: https://github.com/d3/d3-array/issues/142#issuecomment-761861983). But this code is not traversing all YearQtr and seems to return only the last YearQtr per suburb.

```
let data_sales__wide = Array.from(
  d3.group(data_sales, d => d.Suburb),
    ([Suburb, group]) => Object.fromEntries(
      [["Suburb", Suburb]]
        .concat(group.map(d => ['YearQtr', d.YearQtr] ))
        .concat(group.map(d => [d.Type, d.NumSales] ))
    )
)
```

**For additional reference context**: If I take away the `Suburb` dimension from my data, leaving only `YearQtr, Type, NumSales` columns, then the following code works (which is exactly same as Mike Bostock comment):

```
let sales_wide = Array.from(
    d3.group(sales, d => d.YearQtr),
        ([YearQtr, group]) => Object.fromEntries(
        [["YearQtr", YearQtr]].concat(
            group.map(d => [d.Type, d.NumSales])
        )
    )
)
```

So I think it not working because my code is nested between `Suburb` and `YearQtr`.

Any thoughts (*and I'm looking for cleaner/readable code please*)?

Comment: Does the output format need to be: `{ "Suburb": "ardno", "YearQtr": "2002Q1", "House": 40 , "Unit": 50 }` and related issue for `box` with `2011Q2` and `2011Q4` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - output format needs to print one line for every unique `Suburb, YearQtr` pair and provide `House, Unit, Land` values, as applicable, for that combination.

Comment: Your output in the question looks like it has a fault then - `aardno` and `2002Q1` appears twice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RobinMackenzie, I have edited/fixed that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with a nested object to store the values for each combination of values for the two keys.

```js
let arr=[{Suburb:"ardno",YearQtr:"2001Q2",Type:"House",NumSales:10},{Suburb:"ardno",YearQtr:"2001Q2",Type:"Unit",NumSales:20},{Suburb:"ardno",YearQtr:"2001Q2",Type:"Land",NumSales:30},{Suburb:"ardno",YearQtr:"2002Q1",Type:"Unit",NumSales:40},{Suburb:"ardno",YearQtr:"2002Q1",Type:"House",NumSales:50},{Suburb:"keilor",YearQtr:"2006Q4",Type:"House",NumSales:48},{Suburb:"keilor",YearQtr:"2007Q4",Type:"House",NumSales:61},{Suburb:"box",YearQtr:"2011Q2",Type:"House",NumSales:24},{Suburb:"box",YearQtr:"2011Q4",Type:"Unit",NumSales:26},{Suburb:"box",YearQtr:"2008Q3",Type:"Land",NumSales:5}];

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{Suburb,YearQtr,Type,NumSales})=>{
  Object.assign(((acc[Suburb] = acc[Suburb] || {})[YearQtr] 
    = acc[Suburb][YearQtr] || {Suburb, YearQtr}), {[Type]: NumSales});
  return acc;
}, {})).flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @iota - this does the job but reduce is inefficient for larger datasets (per my knowledge). See the note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap that reads:

"Note, however, that this is inefficient and should be avoided for large arrays: in each iteration, it creates a new temporary array that must be garbage-collected, and it copies elements from the current accumulator array into a new array instead of just adding the new elements to the existing array."

Is there a way to achieve the same using `.flatMap()` ?

Comment: @ranaalisaeed It only does that for that particular example because it uses `concat`. That note does not apply generally.

Comment: Okay understood. Can you help me though understand your code better? I'm struggling to work out how it's doing what it's doing? What does this do `((acc[Suburb] = acc[Suburb] || {})[YearQtr] = acc[Suburb][YearQtr] || {Suburb, YearQtr})`? Secondly, what is the rationale for `Object.values(...).flatMap(Object.values)`?

Comment: @ranaalisaeed It creates the object at `acc[Suburb][YearQtr]` if it doesn't already exist. Since we are using a nested object as the accumulator, we need to take `Object.values` twice, hence `Object.values(...).flatMap(Object.values)` is used.